# Unable to execute script on remote host using ssh-plugin - Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am trying to test ssh-plugin on Jenkins to execute the shell script on the remote host. I have added the site and the connection is successful. However, when I tested this `Execute shell script on the remote host using ssh` option inside a freestyle project, I have got the below error message. I was just trying to execute an echo statement which prints `Hello Testing!!` but it gives the below error message saying ***[SSH] Exception: session is down.***

Just trying to understand what does this mean?

[image: Execute shell script on remote host using ssh]